# Using a shader in The Foundry Nuke

Tags: c++, shader, nuke

Is there a way to apply the shader in plugin?

I'm trying to implement anti-aliasing, but all my attempts failed :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this simple:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

#include "DDImage/Knobs.h"
#include "DDImage/DDMath.h"
#include "DDImage/ViewerContext.h"
#include "DDImage/Iop.h"
#include "DDImage/PixelIop.h"
#include "DDImage/Row.h"

using namespace DD::Image;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// GPU File Shader Op.

class GPUFileShader : public DD::Image::PixelIop
{

    const char* shaderFile_;
    std::string currShaderFile_;
    std::string shader_;
    int version_;
    int currVersion_;

    const char* gpuEngine_body() const
    {
        return shader_.c_str();
    }

    void pixel_engine(const Row& in, int y, int x, int r, ChannelMask channels, Row& out)
    {
        foreach(z, channels) {
            const float* inptr = in[z] + x;
            const float* END = inptr + (r - x);
            float* outptr = out.writable(z) + x;
            while (inptr < END)
                *outptr++ = *inptr++;
        }
    }

    void in_channels(int, DD::Image::ChannelSet& c) const { } // return c unchanged

public:
    GPUFileShader(Node* node)
        : PixelIop(node)
        , shaderFile_(0)
        , version_(0)
        , currVersion_(0)
    { }

    void knobs(Knob_Callback f)
    {
        File_knob(f, &shaderFile_, "shader_file", "OpenGL Shading Language file");
    }

    void _validate(bool)
    {
        if (!shaderFile_)
            return;

        if (version_ != currVersion_ || currShaderFile_ != std::string(shaderFile_)) {
            std::ifstream ifs(shaderFile_);
            if (!ifs) {
                Iop::error("Error reading shader file.");
                return;
            }
            std::stringstream str;
            std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(str));
            shader_ = str.str();
            currVersion_ = version_;
            currShaderFile_.assign(shaderFile_);
        }

        copy_info(0);
    }

    static const DD::Image::Op::Description d;
    const char* Class() const { return d.name; }
    const char* node_help() const { return "GPU Op which gets initialised from a file. Customise for proprietary formats. Default assumes OpenGL shading language code."; }

};

static Op* GPUFileShader_c(Node* node) { return new GPUFileShader(node); }
const Op::Description GPUFileShader::d("GPUFileShader", GPUFileShader_c);
```